# Htaccess language Redirect 310 error

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a two language site

```
Swedish side  www.site.com
English side  www.site.com/?lang=en
```

I'm using

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} (aa|ab|af|am|ar|as|ay|az|ba|be|bg|bh|bi|bn|bo|br|ca|co|cs|cy|da|de|dz|el|en|eo|es|et|eu|fa|fi|fj|fo|fr|fy|ga|gd|gl|gn|gu|ha|hi|hr|hu|hy|ia|ie|ik|in|is|it|iw|ja|ji|jw|ka|kk|kl|km|kn|ko|ks|ku|ky|la|ln|lo|lt|lv|mg|mi|mk|ml|mn|mo|mr|ms|mt|my|na|ne|nl|no|oc|om|or|pa|pl|ps|pt|qu|rm|rn|ro|ru|rw|sa|sd|sg|sh|si|sk|sl|sm|sn|so|sq|sr|ss|st|su|sw|ta|te|tg|th|ti|tk|tl|tn|to|tr|ts|tt|tw|uk|ur|uz|vi|vo|wo|xh|yo|zh|zu) [NC]
RewriteRule .* www.site.com/?lang=en [L]
```

To get all languages but Swedish to the `www.site.com/?lang=en` but I end up in a 310 loop.
what is missing ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a check for `lang` to make sure you don't loop.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(&|^)lang=
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} (aa|ab|af|am|ar|as|ay|az|ba|be|bg|bh|bi|bn|bo|br|ca|co|cs|cy|da|de|dz|el|en|eo|es|et|eu|fa|fi|fj|fo|fr|fy|ga|gd|gl|gn|gu|ha|hi|hr|hu|hy|ia|ie|ik|in|is|it|iw|ja|ji|jw|ka|kk|kl|km|kn|ko|ks|ku|ky|la|ln|lo|lt|lv|mg|mi|mk|ml|mn|mo|mr|ms|mt|my|na|ne|nl|no|oc|om|or|pa|pl|ps|pt|qu|rm|rn|ro|ru|rw|sa|sd|sg|sh|si|sk|sl|sm|sn|so|sq|sr|ss|st|su|sw|ta|te|tg|th|ti|tk|tl|tn|to|tr|ts|tt|tw|uk|ur|uz|vi|vo|wo|xh|yo|zh|zu) [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://www.site.com/?lang=%1 [L]
```

Note that the `%1` is a backreference to the 2 letter language code that matched in the previous RewriteCond. The other thing about the Rule to note is that a request like `/something/file.html` will get redirected to `http://www.site.com/?lang=(2 letter language code)`. Essentially, the original path is lost. If you want to keep it, you need to match and use a backreference:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.site.com/$1?lang=%1 [L]
```

If you want previous query strings to also get passed, for example, `/something/file.php?a=b`, you need to add `QSA` in the brackets so that it will get redirected to `http://www.site.com/somthing/file.php?lang=(2 letter language code)&a=b`.

Comment: Thank you ! Code works great but i realized that firefox and chrome has both swedish and english en + eng us as default language meaning they will still be directed to eng side. what code do i need to avoid this ?

Comment: The RewriteCond should match both "en" and "eng" and only use the "en" part.

Comment: dont understand.. most swedish browser has two languages en and sv. since the HTTP:Accept-Language detects english as one installed language it redirects swedish users to /?lang=en  maybe a better solution is redirecting the whole www.site.com to www.site.com/?lang=en but to add an exeption for sv language. but im not sure this is the best way and i dont know how to write that.

Comment: If you're going to do something more complicated you should write a script. Because if a browser says it accepts "en" but instead of using "en" (eventhough the browser says it accepts it), you want to carefully parse through the accept-language to look for a better language, mod_rewrite isn't going to cut it. Here is more about using `Accept-Language` to determine locales: http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-accept-lang-locales