# Dual language browsers redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to redirect all users but Swedish ones to the English side of my site but since Swedish browsers by default have both English and Swedish languages installed they all get redirected to the English side.

```
Swedish : xyz.com
English : xyz.com/?lang=en
```

got some help with this code and it works but not for swedish browsers with enlish installed

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(&|^)lang=
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} (aa|ab|af|am|ar|as|ay|az|ba|be|bg|bh|bi|bn|bo|br|ca|co|cs|cy|da|de|dz|el|en|eo|es|et|eu|fa|fi|fj|fo| fr|fy|ga|gd|gl|gn|gu|ha|hi|hr|hu|hy|ia|ie|ik|in|is|it|iw|ja|ji|jw|ka|kk|kl|km|kn|ko|ks|ku|ky|la|ln|l o|lt|lv|mg|mi|mk|ml|mn|mo|mr|ms|mt|my|na|ne|nl|no|oc|om|or|pa|pl|ps|pt|qu|rm|rn|ro|ru|rw|sa|sd|sg|sh |si|sk|sl|sm|sn|so|sq|sr|ss|st|su|sw|ta|te|tg|th|ti|tk|tl|tn|to|tr|ts|tt|tw|uk|ur|uz|vi|vo|wo|xh|yo| zh|zu) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.xyz.com/$1?lang=%1 [L]
```

How can I do this so every browser is redirected to `xyz.com/?lang=en` but with an exception for Swedish that would stay on `xyz.com`?

Comment: Like I said in your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8130103/htaccess-language-redirect-310-error), if you're going to do something this complicated, .htaccess is going to be insufficient.

Comment: Jon, thanks for the help in previouse post, due to my lacking skills i cannot understand why oits to complicated for htaccess. Shouldnt it ust be a general redirecton with a language exception for SV ?

Comment: From my comment in your last question, there is no conditional logic in .htaccess. For example, there is no "if/then/else" in .htaccess. What you are asking for is parsing the **Accept-Language** header and making informed decisions on what language to actually serve. You **can not** do this using mod_rewrite.

Comment: OK so Accept-Language  cannot make a difference from secondary or primery language ?

Comment: Ok Jon I accept defeat ;) Im going for the script as adviced. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8295596/dual-language-browsers-redirect-javascript

Answer (score 1):

The [`accept-language` string](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.4) is a complicated beast - it can contain multiple values:

```
 se, en-gb;q=0.8, en;q=0.7
```

each of them can also be written in several different ways:

```
 se, se-SE, se-FI, se-EE  // Swedish in .... Sweden, Finland, Estonia
```

While *theoretically* your requirement can surely be reflected in a regex, stuff like this is generally best done in whatever server side language you're using - it's bound to have ready-made libraries to parse `accept-language` properly, and possibly even reduce it to a 2-letter language string, based on which you can then do your redirection.

Comment: My two cents: While complex Accept-Language processing is indeed best done outside .htaccess, the OP's request is so simple I see no reason not to do it in .htaccess. .htaccess can _simulate_ if-then-else perfecly well (the OP's order already does this one of the possible ways), and it can very easily match substrings (not just whole strings). Seems to me all the OP needs is something like: RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \blang=en [OR] - RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} !\bse\b - RewriteRule ... English-Version

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you should try to add a rule that checks if the language doesn't contain swedish... I hope I may assume that swedish browsers have something like "swedish AND english"?

Another option would be to check for swedish language, and "rewrite" to the same, using the [L] option and then append the line after that the lang variable.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(&|^)lang=
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} (se) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1?lang=%1 [L]
```

Comment: Good idea, but the `accept-language` will never consist only of `se`. (See my answer for why)

Comment: Sorry, coundn´t get it to work... I get the 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS)

Comment: Have been trying to modify the code to get it to work but i cant seem to get rid of the redirection loop. Can i set the default page to /?lang=en and than  re/redirect only sv back to xyz.com ?