# Dual language browsers redirect Javascript

Tags: javascript, redirect

I am trying to redirect English browsers to `xyz.com/?lang=en` while letting Swedish ones stay on `xyz.com`

I have been trying :

```
var type=navigator.appName
if (type=="Netscape")
var lang = navigator.language
else
var lang = navigator.userLanguage

//cut down to first 2 chars of country code
var lang = lang.substr(0,2)

// Swedish
if (lang == "sv")
window.location.replace('????')

// if none of above (default to English or any other)
else
window.location.replace('xyz.com/?lang=en')
</script>
```

But I don't know how to write the Swedish URL since it's not a redirection as the default language is swedish... writing the `xyz.com` gets me into a redirection loop

---

```
if ($_REQUEST["lang"] == "en") 
{ 
    echo '<div class="langlight"><a href="http://xyz.com/">Svenska</a></div>';
} 
else 
{
    echo '<div class="langbold"><a href="http://xyz.com/">Svenska</a></div>';

}

if ($_REQUEST["lang"] == "en") 
{
    echo '<div class="langbold"><a href="http://xyz.com/">English</a></div>';
} 
else 
{
    echo '<div class="langlight"><a href="xyz.com/">English</a></div>';
}

    enter code here
```

Comment: why just not doing anything in the case of swedish ? Just do the redirection when it's english and do nothing when it's swedish.

Comment: The correct way to detect the browser language is to inspect the [accept language HTTP header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.4) server-side. Clientside language detection has cross-browser issues and sometimes only detects the installed language (instead of the preferred one)

Comment: since all swedish browsers has english as secondary langue that would redirect them as well

Comment: The script works ! im so happy, i´ve been messing with this for days trying htaccess and diferent script...  thank you !

Comment: Why is serverside detection better ?

Comment: @user1046583, to whose answer are you referring ? You can upvote the answers you like, and also accept the one that solved your problem or helped you most.. Also you can comment directly under an answer so that the user that answer can follow up.. have a read at the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Comment: Ah I see... done ! not use to the structure here..

Answer (score 2):

```
if (lang !== "sv") {
    window.location.replace(window.location.href + '?lang=en');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are always checking the language from the `navigator`.

This way everytime the page loads it will try to reload the page with the altered or not url.

You need to place a condition where it will not reload the page..
That should be when there is a URL parameter passed.

So check for the querystring as well and override the default if a value exists in the url.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function(undefined){
        var queryString = {},
            search = window.location.search.substring(1), // read the current querystring
            searchItems = search.length?search.split('&'):[]; //  and split it at the different params if any exist
        for(var i = 0, len = searchItems.length; i < len; i++){ // for each parameter passed
           var parts = searchItems[i].split('='); // split the key/value pair
           queryString[parts[0].toLowerCase()] = parts[1]; // and store it to our queryString variable
        }

       if (queryString.lang === undefined){ // if there is no lang parameter passed do your checking otherwise skip this step completely and use the url lang parameter.
           var type=navigator.appName, lang = ''; 
           if (type=="Netscape") {
               lang = navigator.language.substr(0,2);
           } else {
               lang = navigator.userLanguage.substr(0,2);
           }
           if (lang != "sv"){
               if (searchItems.length){
                   window.location.replace(window.location.href + '&lang=en');
               } else {
                   window.location.replace(window.location.href + '?lang=en');
               }
           }
       }
    }());
</script>
```

---

**Notice:** Although, as @missingno mentions in his comment to your question, this is best handled server-side than client-side.

Comment: Oh, There is one problem thoe :( there is a language switcher on the site and if and english browser is trying to switch to swedish the script is redirecting him back to english. Is there a workaround for this ?

Comment: @user1046583 can you post the switcher code ? or a link to a live version of the site .. ?

Comment: Posted the code for the language switcher below, It seem that the site got a lot slower now to